# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat not working with time format with timezone

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I want to check if submitted datetime from user is the same as my datetime format with

```
DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)
```

It was working fine until I changed my time format from `Y-m-d H:i:s` to `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.ZP`
I want to get timedate like this 2011-11-09T17:11:57.430+05:00
What format should I give to my function? Is the format I used wrong?

Comment: What is your format? I can't read it while it is buried in a wall of text.

Comment: @RPM I gave my format and sample datetime in my question, this is what I want, I need the right format for 2011-11-09T17:11:57.430+05:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. You have used 'Z' where you should have a 'u' for microseconds, so your code should look something like this:-

```
$dateStr = '2011-11-09T17:11:57.430+05:00';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $dateStr);
var_dump($date);
```

Output:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2011-11-09 17:11:57' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 1
  public 'timezone' => string '+05:00' (length=6)
```

The format strings accepted by `DateTime::createFromFormat()` are the same as those accepted by [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score -1):

That's an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date, and you can simply use [`$format = 'c'`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for that.

Comment: it is not working, probably not working with DateTime::createFromFormat

Comment: The PHP ISO8601 format is something like '2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00'; no microseconds.